# Installing huawei E303 modem GUI on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: usb-modem, modem

Is there any way to install a gui for my modem so I can easily check my data balance? By default there is always a gui available for windows and mac system.

I've tried opening the modem's storage and I found a folder for linux which contains several installation scripts, but I can't make them executable as the storage is read-only

Note: The modem is working properly, I just need a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I copied the whole Linux folder inside the modem storage to my home folder and made the installation scripts executable. Then I ran them from the command line, and after this I got a nice gui which i could use to check my data usage just the way it used to be on windows.

Comment: It would be helpful if you wrote those scripts here too for non technical users